# systemd - how to access current user name from system service?

Tags: linux, service, systemd, systemctl

I want to create system service, which (for each user) will be started just after user login and do some job inside user's $HOME with root privelegies.

Here is sample service:

```
[Unit]
Description= My User service
After=dbus.service

[Service]
StandardError=journal
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "cp -r $HOME/.config /root/backup/$USER/$(date)/"  #<- just a sample root task

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

But $HOME or $USER variables are unavailable. How to access them?

Comment: You can specify the directives User= and Group= in the [Service] section of the unit file.

Comment: But how can it help?

Comment: Have you tried ? Did you have $HOME and $USER ?

Comment: for system(without --user) service $USER is always root unless it not set statically in User=

Comment: You meant you have tried `User=`, but $USER is still not available ?

Comment: I don't tried User= because I don't have it, because I need to retrieve it in runtime.

Comment: I thought you want to run as a normal user, not as root.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [unit specifiers](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers) to accomplish this:

`%h` represents the home folder of the user

`%u` gets the name of the user

```
[Unit]
Description= My User service
After=dbus.service

[Service]
StandardError=journal
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "cp -r %h/.config /root/backup/%u/$(date)/"  #<- just a sample root task

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to access actual user environment variables from a 'system' unit the way you're envisioning.

The approach I would probably use for the example you gave is to have a 'system' `path` unit that starts at boot and watches for a `.needsbackup` file in each user's home dir, extracts the username from the path, and in turn triggers your 'system' backup `service` unit — probably using a template unit so each run of the backup service would get its own instance, eg `backup@<user>.service`. This makes it easy to pass the username to your backup command, and allows you to see from a glance at your list of running units what user(s) have a backup job running at any given moment. Delete the .needsbackup file *before* starting the backup command for obvious reasons, and if you want the backup to run every time the user logs in, you can add `touch ~/.needsbackup` to their .profile (or /etc/profile to make it apply to all users).

I believe there is a more technically correct, elegant way to detect user login directly by having your system `service` unit hook into the logind D-BUS API, but I can't offer any help there, as I'm really not familiar with those components.

Also note that your question asks about a 'system' service, but your example service file is a 'user' service file. In particular, `default.target` is only useful in user units. For your 'system' unit, you probably want either `multi-user.target` or `graphical.target`.